# onOptionsItemSelected not being called from within fragment

Tags: java, android

For some reason, my optionItemSelected is not being called when i click the button associated with it. The timber log is not called, but this appears in the logs the moment after i click the button:

```sh
D/ViewRootImpl@ba4d36e[POIHistoryFlowActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@ba4d36e[POIHistoryFlowActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
```

Here is the code i have:

```java
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu, final MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_recent_destinations, menu);
        Timber.d("Menu was inflated");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(final MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_action_item_clear:
                Timber.d("Clear button was clicked");
                // clear the destinations
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

In similar fragments, the parent's activity does not override either `onCreateOptionsItem()` nor `onOptionsItemSelected()`, but their associated buttons work while in this fragment they do not and after combing through everything with the debugger I'm at a loss as to what the root cause could be. Any help would me super appreciated!

update:
activity_recent_destinations.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_action_item_clear"
        android:title="@string/menu_item_title_clear"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/action_item_clear"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

Comment: Can you post both the code for the host Activity and the contents for the `R.menu.activity_recent_destinations`?

Comment: Updated as requested

Comment: So you're using an `app:actionLayout`. Is the button you're actually clicking on _inside_ that layout? If so, you aren't going to get a callback for the menu item itself. You need to get a reference to the inflated view and add a standard click listener.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using an "action layout" for this item. This is just going to act like a normal view and clicking on it won't trigger the `onOptionsItemSelected` callback. You have to get a reference to the layout itself and add a click listener:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu, final MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_recent_destinations, menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_action_item_clear);
    View actionView = item.getActionView();
    // Set the listener on the root view or any children if necessary
    actionView.setOnClickListener(...);
}
```

Comment: I would generally do this inside `onCreateOptionsMenu`, yeah. Let me update the answer to make that more explicit.

Comment: Ah it looks like you do this from the createOptionsMenu method. Thank you so much!!